# How to send a `vararg variadicArguments: kotlin.Any?` to a GObject native call with Kotlin Native?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native, gobject, gobject-introspection, cinterop

I'm working on a GIR generator to create Kotlin Native bindings for GTK and other GObject based libraries. I reached a stage where I can almost compile the bindings for GLib but I'm stuck with the handling of `vararg`s.

For example `g_string_append_printf`, which is mapped with this:

```
kotlinx.cinterop.internal.CCall public external fun g_string_append_printf(string: kotlinx.cinterop.CValuesRef<native.glib.GString /* = native.glib._GString */>?, @kotlinx.cinterop.internal.CCall.CString format: kotlin.String?, vararg variadicArguments: kotlin.Any?): kotlin.Unit { /* compiled code */ }
```

It seems to expect a `vararg variadicArguments: kotlin.Any?`, but if I send that to it like this:

```
    public fun appendPrintf(format: String, vararg variadicArguments: Any): Unit {
        g_string_append_printf(cPointer.reinterpret(), format, variadicArguments)
    }
```

I get this error when I build the module:

```
type kotlin.Array<out kotlin.Any>  is not supported here: doesn't correspond to any C type
```

The GIR parameter only gives a name (`...`) and has a tag `varargs`:

```
          <parameter name="..." transfer-ownership="none">
            <doc xml:space="preserve"
                 filename="glib-2.0.c"
                 line="32361">the parameters to insert into the format string</doc>
            <varargs/>
          </parameter>
```

But there are no other information about the type.

What should this `vararg variadicArguments: kotlin.Any?` be converted to?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: this is not supported in Kotlin/Native at the moment, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-56164

**Original answer:**

I'm not very experienced in Kotlin/Native nor CInterop, but I know that to pass an array to a function that expects a `vararg`, you have to explicitly *spread* it (unlike in Java) using the spread operator (`*variadicArguments`):

```kotlin
public fun appendPrintf(format: String, vararg variadicArguments: Any): Unit {
    g_string_append_printf(cPointer.reinterpret(), format, *variadicArguments)
}
```

Here is the [relevant piece](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs) of the doc:

> If you already have an array and want to pass its contents to the function, use the spread operator (prefix the array with *)

Comment: Unfortunately the spread is not supported at the moment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-56164/Native-Unclear-errors-when-calling-cinterop-generated-function-with-vararg-Any#focus=Comments-27-6871657.0-0

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't know this wasn't supported in Native. I added a link to the issue in the answer